# Добавить строки в файл в указанном месте [решен]

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

К примеру есть файл stat.html, в нем таблица. Возможно ли средствами php добавить в файл, а именно в таблицу после

```
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
```

следующий tr ?
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>

---

Олег Б, не плохо =)

К сожалению такое не прокатит. В задании необходимо сгенерировать статический html файл. И каждый раз его обновлять.

---

Есть файл, в нем таблица. К примеру в таблице данные касательно ссылок на сайте. Когда на сайт добавляется ссылка, нужно взять этот файл, открыть и в конец таблицы дописать еще данные, тоесть еще 1 tr.

---

**Большое спасибо, вопрос решен**

Comment: для записи в файл : http://www.php.su/functions/?fwrite

Но как я думаю, Вы непонимаете что Вам нужно сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файл нужно статический?

---

перед тегом `</table>` добавте например `<!--  Add here  -->`

Так:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>
<!--  Add here  -->
</table>
```

---

файле test1.php

- генерируете новые строки таблицы в переменную $newrows
- К $newrows добавляете `<!--  Add here  -->` Прим: `$newrows .=  '<!--  Add here  -->';`
- Затем Работаете с фалом:
- $file = 'stat.html'; // расположение файла
- `$FileSourse = file_get_content($file);` // весь html код файла
- `$FileSourse = str_replace('<!--  Add here  -->',$newrows,$FileSourse);` // Добавляете новые строки в код посредством замены `<!--  Add here  -->` на новые сгенерированые строки.
- `file_put_contents($file, $FileSourse);` // перезапись файла с новым кодом

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте расширение файла на stat.php и вставляйте сколько угодно:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <table>
     <?php for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```